# Mathematical Proof Question?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

How would prove that this is true for all $k \geq 6$:

$$\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{k+1} - \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{k+1} \geq   (1.5)^{k} \times \sqrt{5} $$

Comment: This was a longer more complicated inequality and then I got stuck at this, I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Note that $\varphi\approx1.618>1.5$ and $\left|\frac1{\varphi}\right|\approx0.618$, so $\varphi^{k+1}$ increases faster than $(1.5)^k$, and $\left(-\frac1{\varphi}\right)^{k+1}\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^{k+1}-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^{k+1}}{(1.5)^k\sqrt5}=\frac3{2\sqrt5}\left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}3\right)^{k+1}-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}3\right)^{k+1}\right)\tag{1}$$

The inequality that you’re trying to prove is equivalent to showing that $(1)$ is $\ge 1$ for all $k\ge 6$, which in turn is equivalent to showing that

$$\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}3\right)^{k+1}-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}3\right)^{k+1}\ge\frac{2\sqrt5}3\tag{2}$$

for all $k\ge 6$.

It’s actually easier to show a stronger statement:

$$\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}3\right)^{k+1}-\left|\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}3\right)^{k+1}\right|\ge\frac{2\sqrt5}3\tag{3}$$

for all $k\ge 6$. You can check by direct computation that this is true when $k=6$. Then note that $\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}3>1$ and $\left|\dfrac{1-\sqrt5}3\right|<1$, so that as $k$ increases, the first term on the lefthand side of $(3)$ increases and the second decreases.

Comment: @Zain: You’re welcome; glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

In fact it is true for $k \geq 5$. If you know [Binet's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Philippe_Marie_Binet), life becomes a lot easier. The inequality is then equivalent to $F_{k+1} \geq 1.5^k$, where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number. We can easily check that $F_6=8 \geq 1.5^5$ and $F_7=13 \geq 1.5^6$, and if it is true for $5 \leq k \leq i, i\geq 6$, we have $F_{i+2}=F_{i+1}+F_{i} \geq 1.5^{i}+1.5^{i-1}=2.5(1.5^{i-1}) \geq 1.5^{i+1}$, so we are done by induction.